# Adjust Tableview height and cells dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to adjust the height of the tableview. I want to adjust it whenever the keyboard disappears. The tableview height should increase. In addition, any cells that had data on them should move downwards as well. They should move downwards to reflect the new height of the tableview. How can I do this?

This is my code right now:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var items = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pear"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of UITableViewCell.")
    }

    var item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.Label.text = item

    //Some adjustments
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the bottom constraint of your tableview as follows by drag and drop of the constraint from xib file to your class file. (This bottom constraint is the bottom of tableview when there is no keyboard visible)

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Add keyboard observers like below

```
    func setKBObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

Modify height based on keyboard's visibility like follows

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
            view.setNeedsLayout()
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this solution. After adding a bottom constraint, it forces me to add constraints for the width, X position, and Y position of the tableview. After adding these constraints, there are several strange errors that seems to pop up randomly. Sometimes, when the tableView has expanded and there is data in the rows, the rows become much wider than normal. Sometimes, when the tableview has expanded, there are lines (cell separators) for some of the cells but not for other cells, when there should be no lines at all. Do you know how to avoid these problems?

Comment: Remove width and give appropriate leading and trailing constraints 
Also, for height problems have you given rowHeight as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ?

Comment: It forces me to add the width constraint. If I don't add the width constraint it gives me an error. I have also added leading and trailing constraints. In viewDidLoad I have added "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension" and "tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140."

Comment: If you have added leading trailing top bottom correctly, it won't ask you for width. and cell separators being not visible for some cells can also be a simulator issue (max zoom on simulator or check in device)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var isKeyboardOpen:Bool = false
    @IBOutlet weak var tblheight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.updateViewConstraints()
            let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            if self.tableView.contentSize.height  > screenHeight{
                if isKeyboardOpen == true{
                     self.tblheight.constant = screenHeight - 320
                }else{
                     self.tblheight.constant = screenHeight - 100
                }

            }
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        }

// textField Delegate Method..
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        isKeyboardOpen = true
        viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        isKeyboardOpen = false
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        isKeyboardOpen = false
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

try this.. It works for me.
Hope It will be helpful..